# Make WebView from WebKit draggable by mouse in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, webkit, webview

I would like to create a kind of desktop widget and want it to be very easy to style via HTML/CSS. I decided to use `WebView` for this task.

I have got a borderless `NSWindow` with a `WebView` inside. I want to make it draggable using mouse (as any ordinary window can be dragged using its title, but by clicking anywhere inside my `WebView`). Tried to subclass `WebView` and override `mouseDown` and `mouseDragged` events, but that didn't work (for obvious reasons).

For sure, I can create a transparent view above `WebView` to solve the problem, but I really want to find a better way. Does anybody know how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was solved by overriding the `- (void)sendEvent:` method in the parent `NSWindow` subclass, like this:

```
//Overriding mouse events
- (void)sendEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    if ([theEvent type] == NSLeftMouseDown)
    {
        [self mouseDown:theEvent];
    }
    else if ([theEvent type] == NSLeftMouseDragged)
    {
        [self mouseDragged:theEvent];
    }
    else
    {
        [super sendEvent:theEvent];
    }
}
```

I guess this is the best solution.